# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo caused by NullPointerException

Tags: android

When I run this code:

```
    package com.herring.android.finalproject;


    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
    public class GamesListActivity extends ListActivity {
        private Cursor gamesCursor;
        private GameDataBaseManager mDbHelper;
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.toprated);
            mDbHelper = new GameDataBaseManager(this);
            mDbHelper.open();
            fillData();
            registerForContextMenu(getListView());
            final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
            lv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(GamesListActivity.this, Game.class);
                    startActivityForResult(i, 0);
                }
            });

        }
        private void fillData()
        {
            gamesCursor = mDbHelper.getAllGames();
            startManagingCursor(gamesCursor);
            String[] from = new String[]{GameDataBaseManager.KEY_TITLE};
            int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};
            SimpleCursorAdapter games = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.toprateditem, gamesCursor, from, to);
            setListAdapter(games);
        }
    }
```

I get this in Logcat:

```
01-18 17:46:08.742: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1382): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
01-18 17:46:08.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1382): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.herring.android.finalproject/com.herring.android.finalproject.GamesListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-18 17:46:08.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1382):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
01-18 17:46:08.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1382):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
01-18 17:46:08.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1382):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
01-18 17:46:08.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1382):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
01-18 17:46:08.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1382):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-18 17:46:08.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1382):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-18 17:46:08.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1382):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
01-18 17:46:08.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1382):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-18 17:46:08.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1382):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-18 17:46:08.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1382):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
01-18 17:46:08.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1382):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
01-18 17:46:08.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1382):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-18 17:46:08.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1382): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-18 17:46:08.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1382):     at com.herring.android.finalproject.GamesListActivity.onCreate(GamesListActivity.java:23)
01-18 17:46:08.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1382):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-18 17:46:08.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1382):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
01-18 17:46:08.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1382):     ... 11 more
```

The error occurs at lv.setOnClickListener
I have searched everywhere for an answer, but they all seem to talk about missing setContentView, which I am not.  I am totally lost.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Here is my toprated.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ListView 
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If the `NullPointerException` is on `lv.setOnClickListener()`, then `lv` is null. It's null probably for one of two reasons: either `findViewById()` couldn't find the ID, or `setContentView()` had trouble inflating that XML element. Check to make sure all your IDs are correct (is `R.id.text1` a ListView?), and double check the XML itself.

Comment: @Stephen: Are you sure that `R.id.text1` is the correct `id`? Also, if it is, you shouldn't be using `View.OnClickListener` you should be using the `ListActivity` `onListItemClick` which is automatically setup for the default `ListView` in a `ListActivity`.

Answer (score 1):

```
final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
```

instead of that why not just do getListView()? something like below and try?

```
final ListView lv = getListView();
```

Answer (score 0):

When using ListActivity you **MUST** set the ListView id like this: `android:id="@+id/android:list"`

Comment: @Rotemmiz: Incorrect. For a `ListActivity` the id must be `android:id="@android:id/list"`. If you're simply using a `ListView` in a normal `Activity` you can give it any `id`,

Comment: I was referring to his implementation, but you are right, my formulering is wrong, changing that... :)

Comment: @Rotemmiz: Yes it's difficult to tell without his `toprated.xml` layout file to look at.

Answer (score 0):

You put the listView id text1 but you did not declare it in your layout. You implement listactivity class so you can call listview by this way

```
final ListView lv = getListView();
```

You have declared the listview magic id in your Layout so it is not needed to use findViewById() method. Instead of this you can use `final ListView lv = getListView();`

So write the following code:

```
final ListView lv = getListView();
            lv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(GamesListActivity.this, Game.class);
                    startActivityForResult(i, 0);
                }
            });
```